# Data Transformer vs.Constraints

Tags: symfony, symfony4, pimcore

I stumbled upon a question regarding [`Symfony`'s `DataTransformer`s](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) and how to properly use them. While I know how to implement and add them to my form field, I was wondering how `DataTransformer`s are supposed to be combined with [`Constraint`s](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html).

> The following code shows my use case.

#### The Form

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\Consent\ConsentTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;

class ConsentTestForm extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var ConsentTransformer $consentTransformer */
    private $consentTransformer;

    /**
     * ConsentTestForm constructor.
     * @param ConsentTransformer $consentTransformer
     */
    public function __construct(ConsentTransformer $consentTransformer)
    {
        $this->consentTransformer = $consentTransformer;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('accountConsent', CheckboxType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new IsTrue()
            ]
        ]);
        $builder->get('accountConsent')->addModelTransformer($this->consentTransformer);

        $builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

#### The Model

```php
<?php

class User extends Concrete implements \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\DirtyIndicatorInterface
{
    protected $accountConsent;

    /**
     * ...
     */
    public function getAccountConsent () {
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * ...
     */
    public function setAccountConsent ($accountConsent) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> A lot of code was omitted for the sake of brevity. The model is a [Pimcore class](https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/index.html).

#### The DataTransformer

```php
<?php

namespace Passioneight\Bundle\FormBuilderBundle\Form\DataTransformer\Consent;

use Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Data\Consent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class ConsentTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     * @param Consent|null $consent
     */
    public function transform($consent)
    {
        return $consent instanceof Consent && $consent->getConsent();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     * @param bool|null $consented
     */
    public function reverseTransform($consented)
    {
        $consent = new Consent();
        $consent->setConsent($consented ?: false);
        return $consent;
    }
}
```

> As you can see any submitted value (i.e., `null`, `true`, `false`) will be converted to a [`Consent`](https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Consent.html) and vice-versa.

#### The Controller

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\ConsentTestForm;
use AppBundle\Model\DataObject\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class TestController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 *
 * @Route("/test")
 */
class TestController extends AbstractFrontendController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/form")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function formAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();

        $form = $this->createForm(ConsentTestForm::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                p_r("VALID");
                p_r($user);
            } else {
                p_r("NOT VALID");
            }
        };

        return $this->renderTemplate(':Test:form.html.twig', [
            "form" => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

> Note how a `new User()` is passed as entity in order to automatically populate it with the submitted values.

#### The View

```php
{{ form(form) }}
```

#### The Problem

The form can be built just fine, ultimately, displaying a checkbox with my specified label. Due to the transformer, the `checked`-state is even correctly displayed, as the `transform` method converts the `User`s `Consent` into a `boolean`.

However, when submitting the form, an error is displayed, saying that the account-consent is required. While this is fine when it comes to submitting the form without giving consent, it's not quite the desired outcome when acutally consenting.

When consenting, the submitted value is converted to a `Consent`, which will then hold the value `true`. But since the *transformation is done before the submitted value is validated* the beforementioned error is displayed. This happens, because the `accountConsent` field that was added in the form has a `Constraint` set, namely, `IsTrue`. Due to this, the `IsTrueValidator` validates the `Consent` (instead of the actually submitted value).

> Obviously, the `IsTrueValidator` cannot know about Pimcore's `Consent` class.

### The Question

All of this leaves me with the question: **how do I properly combine the `IsTrue`-constraint with my `ConsentDataTransformer`?**

Comment: It can be challenging to find the right balance between providing too little information and too much information in a question.  I admit I got lost in your details.  I would suggest trying to isolate the issue by making an entity/form with just the constraint field.  I think a [view transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#about-model-and-view-transformers) might help.  But it's really just a guess.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback - much appreciated. I will create a simpler use case and then re-phrase my question. Though, it may take a while until I find the time to do so. I'll also check out if a view transformer helps, but wouldn't the view transformer cause the exact same issue, due to the validation being done after the transformation?

Comment: It's frowned upon a bit on this site but creating a new project, adding the minimum necessary to recreate the issue then checking the entire thing into github can make it easier to trouble shoot a problem such as this.  Just a thought.

Comment: I tried to simplify the question as much as I could - hopefully, it's now clearer what I'm trying to achieve. I still need some time to try the `addViewTransformer` method instead of the `addModelTransformer` method.

Comment: Using `addViewTransformer` causes a similar issue, due to the `CheckboxType` adding another view transformer under the hood, namely, `BooleanToStringTransformer`. This transformer expects the passed value to be of type `string`. Since the submitted value was already converted to a `Consent`, a `TransformationFailedException` is thrown, causing the form to be invalid.

Comment: have you tried how this works when you remove the IsTrue constraint? because I believe CheckboxType is required by default (as in, will mark the html box `required`) and if left empty form will already complain ...

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion. I've removed the `IsTrue` constraint. The `CheckboxType` is indeed `required` by default. However, when setting the HTML attribute `novalidate` (i.e., `<form ... novalidate="novalidate">`), the form will still submit. Submitting the form both with and without the `DataTransformer` (as `ModelTransformer`) will result in the form submission to be _valid_ (independent of whether the checkbox was checked). Adding the `DataTransformer` as `ViewTransformer` will yield the beforementioned error (due to `BooleanToStringTransformer`).

Comment: @mcuenez have you found a solution? I have a similar issue.

Comment: @YohannTilotti sorry I'm not sure what I came up with. Does the accepted answer not work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the validation is you are trying to validate object as boolean type. Constraints are always executed when you try to validate and transformers when you submit the form. So you have already transformed the data and that is why `IsBool` validation fails because the value is in type Consent object; not boolean.

To solve this you have to create new validation constraint overwriting IsTrue.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;

class IsConsented extends IsTrue
{
    public $message = 'You need to consent!';
}
```

And a validator on the same namespace;

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrueValidator;

class IsConsentedValidator extends IsTrueValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        return parent::validate($value->getConsent(), $constraint);
    }
}
```

Then you need to change your `IsTrue` constraint with `IsConsented` as follows;

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\DataTransformer\ConsentTransformer;
use App\Form\Validator\IsConsented;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ConsentTestFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var ConsentTransformer $consentTransformer */
    private $consentTransformer;

    /**
     * ConsentTestForm constructor.
     * @param ConsentTransformer $consentTransformer
     */
    public function __construct(ConsentTransformer $consentTransformer)
    {
        $this->consentTransformer = $consentTransformer;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('accountConsent', CheckboxType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new IsConsented()
            ]
        ]);
        $builder->get('accountConsent')->addModelTransformer($this->consentTransformer);

        $builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

That is it. Your form is valid now. The output should look like;

```
FormController.php on line 30:
"VALID"
```

Comment: Thank you for proposing this solution. Unfortunately, I was already aware of this and I'm looking for a different way to solve my issue. The reason being that I'm creating a bundle myself and don't want to have the developers be aware of a custom constraint (as I believe that it would only add complexity). However, at this point it seems to be the only solution, so I'll accept this answer as it _does_ solve the problem and is properly documented.